# Unable to trigger updateQueryData in redux-toolkit

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am trying to call updateQueryData() on mutation in redux-toolkit api but somehow it is not calling. I see args is printing fine when I try to update the data, it just prints args outside updateQueryData but data is never coming inside updateQueryData

Here is my code:

```
export const additionalInputsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'additionalInputsApi',
  baseQuery: getBaseQuery(),
  keepUnusedDataFor: 90,
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getAdditionalInputData: builder.query({
      query: ({ scenarioType, sectorType, ccaVersion, companyId }) => ({
        url: endpoints.GET_ADDITIONAL_INPUT,
        params: {
          ccaVersion,
          scenarioType,
          sectorType,
          ...(companyId && { companyId })
        }
      }),
    }),
    updateAdditionalInputs: builder.mutation({
      query: data => utils.serviceLayerAPI.reduxPost(endpoints.SAVE_ADDITIONAL_INPUTS, data),
      async onQueryStarted(args, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {

        try {
          const { data: updatedPost } = await queryFulfilled

          dispatch(
            additionalInputsApi.util.updateQueryData('getAdditionalInputData', args.key, (draft) => {
              console.log('draft', draft); // Not printing anything
            })
          )
        } catch { }
      },
    })
  })
});

export const {
  useGetAdditionalInputDataQuery,
  useUpdateAdditionalInputsMutation,
} = additionalInputsApi;
```

Here is my store

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const middlewares = [
  sagaMiddleware,
  additionalInputsApi.middleware
];

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    additionalInputs: additionalInputsReducer,
    [additionalInputsApi.reducerPath]: additionalInputsApi.reducer
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: false
  }).concat(middlewares)
});

globalStore.RegisterStore('cca', store);

export default store;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

Can somebody look at my code and tell what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't print anything on dispatch, you don't have a cache entry for the `getAdditionalInputData` endpoint with the argument `args.key`.

That seems likely, since your `getAdditionalInputData` endpoint takes an argument in the form `{ scenarioType, sectorType, ccaVersion, companyId }` and I assume that `args.key` is probably very different from that object.

Comment: I tried to console args.key and I found

{
    "companyId": [],
    "scenario": "NGFS_PHASE_3",
    "sector": "AIRLINES",
    "version": "V5"
}

Comment: Those are very different properties than what the `getAdditionalInputData` endpoint accepts. To change the data of an endpoint, you have to identify it with the exact data it was originally called with.

Comment: You were correct, I send correct data and it worked. Thanks